# Pattern search in satellite imagery

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite, digital-image-processing, feature-extraction

I would like to search for the specific buildings (polyhouse in my case) on the map like the one shown [here](https://goo.gl/ZDDiLt)

[image]

Are there any free options available which can give me lat and lng of such shapes/features in specified area?

Comment: What type of imagery are you working with?

Comment: @Aaron I am completely new to this. I was thinking, I should be able to do this with google maps.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really an answer, but it is funny that I just saw an article today about this problem. Maybe it will lead you in the right direction.

http://www.nextgov.com/big-data/2016/05/promise-terrapattern-visual-search-engine-satellite-imagery/128673/

> Terrapattern, a visual search engine for satellite imagery, released
>   this week by a team of artists and geographers at Carnegie Mellon
>   University. It is Google’s “reverse image-search” tool for maps,
>   basically: Click on a spot you find interesting, and Terrapattern will
>   show you other spots on the map like it.

Looks promising, but...

> Right now, Terrapattern only covers four American cities: Pittsburgh,
>   Detroit, San Francisco and New York City. Terrapattern is so
>   computing-hungry that it is effectively a proof of concept right now,
>   at least for a team of artists working with less than $35,000. Each
>   metro region takes about 10 gigabytes of RAM—not storage, but active
>   memory.

If it is true that regions can use upwards of 10gb of active memory, then it isn't likely you'll find an easy or free solution right now.

Answer (score 0):

DigitalGlobe offers a GBDX service that lets you deploy your object detection algorithms against the worlds largest satellite image archive:
http://developer.digitalglobe.com/gbdx/

I think their free developer tier includes some algorithms that would help you get started. Getting acurrate building footprints with a fully automated algorithm is tough though!

Disclaimer: used to work at DigitalGlobe